# Selenium Dropbox hidden is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selenium

Hello I am stuck with Selenium Webdriver, I have a dropdown with the next Html

```
<div class="form_option">
    <label for="dia">Fecha de nacimiento: <sup>*</sup></label>
    <label id="errorDOB" class="error" style="display: none;"></label>
    <input id="dateOfBirth" style="display:none;" name="dateOfBirth" value="" class="selectized" type="text"/><input name="_D:dateOfBirth" value=" " type="hidden"/>
    <div class="third_one">
        <select name="dia" id="dia" required placeholder="Día">
            <option value="">Día</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="third_two">
        <select name="mes" id="mes" required placeholder="Mes">
            <option value="">Mes</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="third_three">
        <select name="anho" id="anho" required placeholder="Año">
            <option value="">Año</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see this id="dateOfBirh" it’s hidden, and I have 3 combobox like id="dia" id="mes" id="anho", and when you click in every option, a list open for every case, like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dvZA.png)

I am trying the next from Selenium Webdriver:

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('dia').click();");
```

And I receive the following message:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: document.getElementById(...) is null
Command duration or timeout: 382 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
System info: host: 'DES-ITE-27', ip: '172.17.168.14', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=45.0.2, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 313909be-60c3-42ea-8dbe-1cac6e3addde
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:577)
    at Registro2.testRegistro2(Registro2.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: document.getElementById(...) is null
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
System info: host: 'DES-ITE-27', ip: '172.17.168.14', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.anonymous(about:blank line 69 > Function:1)
    at <anonymous class>.handleEvaluateEvent(about:blank:69)
```

For me is logical that the option it’s not visible but I don’t have the options in html to indicate what is the option that I want to choice, I think this options are generated for JavaScript and are not in the jsp.
I don’t know what to do to indicate the value of every combo box and fulfill the form for finish my job.